# Minesweeper revealing cells in C

Tags: c, recursion, minesweeper

I am trying to write a minesweeper program in C.
What I am trying to achieve here is when user steps on one cell, the cells near without bombs and hint numbers will be revealed.
For example, if `x` is the cell stepped on, `o` is an empty but concealed square, `.` is an empty but revealed cell and `*` is the bomb (hidden when playing of course):

```
x o o o o
o o o * o
o o o o o
```

will result in:

```
. . 1 o o
. . 1 * o
. . 1 o o
```

Here is part of the code:

```
while (1)
{
    printf("Row? ");
    scanf("%d", &row);
    printf("column? ");
    scanf("%d", &clos);
    if (row < 9 && row >= 0 && clos < 8 && clos >= 0)
        break;
    printf("\nInvalid Location\n\n");
}

if (real_map[row][clos] =='*')
{
    print_map_win(display_map,real_map);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Flags Left = %d\n\n\n", flag_left);
    printf("Game Over\n");
    exit(0);
}
else
{
    if (real_map[row][clos] == ' ')
    {
        display_map[row][clos] = real_map[row][clos];
        bonos_reveal(display_map, real_map, clos, row);
        // [[[bonos_reveal is the function I am asking for]]]
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        display_map[row][clos] = real_map[row][clos];
    }
}
```

in which `real_map` has the hint number and bombs in it, and `display_map` is the current state of the map.

edit: I have the following code, and it only reveals in one direction:

```
int bonos_reveal(int disp_map[MAP_ROWS][MAP_COLS], int real_map[MAP_ROWS][MAP_COLS], int clos, int row)
{
    disp_map[row][clos] = real_map[row][clos];

    if (row < 9 && row >= 0 && clos < 8 && clos >= 0)
    {
        if (real_map[row][clos+1] == ' ')
        {
            bonos_reveal(disp_map, real_map, clos + 1, row);
        }
        else
        {
            disp_map[row][clos+1] = real_map[row][clos+1];
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I have no idea how to loop through the cells.

Comment: so your question is... ?

Comment: to fill the function to do the job mentioned. Every method tried will create a stack overflow.

Comment: When you get a stack overflow your termination criterion for your function is wrong. When a tile is already revealed or if it lies outside the grid, stop. Otherwise reveal the tile (or mark it as revealed) and recurse to the adjacent tiles only if it is blank, i.e. has zero adjacent bombs.

Comment: A common problem with Minesweeper implementations is the representation of the cells. There are two independent pieces of information for each cell: What it is (blank, a number from 1 to 8 or a bomb) and its state (revealed, covered and flagged).

Comment: @MOehm display_map will have the ststus of the cell ie blank(' '), numbers, or not revealed('.'). I have also updated the code above.

Comment: I see. The function should only look at the current tile. Also, you seem to reveal blank tiles, not covered tiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here's an example implementation. It uses the following values for tiles:

- 0 to 8: an unmined tile; the number represents the pre-calculated number of adjacent mines
- 9: a mine; this special value is defined as `BOMB`.

Covered tiles have 10 added to that, flagged tiles (not used here) have 20 added to that. You can test whether a tile is mined with:

```
board[row][col] % 10 == BOMB
```

I'll let the code do the explaining:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ROWS 12
#define COLS 20
#define BOMBS 8

#define BOMB 9

void inc(int board[ROWS][COLS], int row, int col)
{
    if (row < 0 || row >= ROWS) return;
    if (col < 0 || col >= COLS) return;
    if (board[row][col] % 10 == BOMB) return;
    board[row][col]++;
}

/*
 *      Set up board and pre-calculate adjacent bombs
 */
void board_init(int board[ROWS][COLS])
{
    int i, j, n;

    for (j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < COLS; i++) {
            board[j][i] = 10;
        }
    }

    n = 0;
    while (n < BOMBS) {
        j = rand() % ROWS;
        i = rand() % COLS;

        if (board[j][i] % 10 != BOMB) {
            board[j][i] = 19;
            inc(board, j - 1, i - 1);
            inc(board, j - 1, i);
            inc(board, j - 1, i + 1);
            inc(board, j,     i - 1);
            inc(board, j,     i + 1);
            inc(board, j + 1, i - 1);
            inc(board, j + 1, i);
            inc(board, j + 1, i + 1);
            n++;
        }
    }
}

/*
 *      Reveal tile and propagate revelation
 */
void board_reveal(int board[ROWS][COLS], int row, int col)
{
    if (row < 0 || row >= ROWS) return;     /* skip off-board tiles */
    if (col < 0 || col >= COLS) return;

    if (board[row][col] < 10) return;       /* already revealed, skip */
    if (board[row][col] >= 20) return;      /* must remove flag first, skip */

    if (board[row][col] % 10 == BOMB) {
        int i, j;

        printf("Bang!\n");

        for (j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
            for (i = 0; i < COLS; i++) {
                if (board[j][i] % 10 == BOMB) board[j][i] = BOMB;
            }
        }     
    } else {
        board[row][col] %= 10;
        if (board[row][col] == 0) {
            board_reveal(board, row - 1, col);
            board_reveal(board, row, col - 1);
            board_reveal(board, row, col + 1);
            board_reveal(board, row + 1, col);
        }
    }
}

void board_print(int board[ROWS][COLS])
{
    int i, j;

    for (j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
        putchar(' ');

        for (i = 0; i < COLS; i++) {
            const char *tile = ".12345678*##########PPPPPPPPPP";
            int k = board[j][i];

            putchar(tile[k]);
        }

        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main()
{
    int board[ROWS][COLS];

    srand(time(NULL));
    board_init(board);
    board_reveal(board, 0, 0);
    board_print(board);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i modified my code to meet the logic of your code. It works! Thanks!